# Detecting ViewDidUnload from a child control

Tags: c#, ios, .net, xamarin, system.reactive

I'm trying to figure out how I can hook into `ViewDidUnload` on a control's superview. To illustrate why I need this, consider my `ControlFactory` class, which produces `UIButton`s (amongst other controls):

```
internal static class ControlFactory
{
        private static readonly IObservable<Unit> sharedDynamicTypeChanged = TinyIoCContainer.Current
            .Resolve<ISystemNotificationsService>()
            .DynamicTypeChanged
            .Publish()
            .RefCount();

        public static UIButton CreateButton()
        {
            return new DynamicTypeAwareButton(sharedDynamicTypeChanged, UIFont.PreferredHeadline);
        }
}
```

The idea here is that every `UIButton` produced by the factory will automatically scale its font based on the user's dynamic type setting. My `DynamicTypeAwareButton` is an inner class that looks like this:

```
private sealed class DynamicTypeAwareButton : UIButton
{
    private readonly IObservable<Unit> dynamicTypeChanged;
    private readonly UIFont font;
    private IDisposable subscription;

    public DynamicTypeAwareButton(IObservable<Unit> dynamicTypeChanged, UIFont font)
    {
        this.dynamicTypeChanged = dynamicTypeChanged;
        this.font = font;
    }

    public override void MovedToSuperview()
    {
        base.MovedToSuperview();

        // TODO: figure out when to subscribe/unsubscribe
        this.subscription = this.dynamicTypeChanged
            .StartWith(Unit.Default)
            .Subscribe(_ => this.UpdateFont());
    }

    private void UpdateFont()
    {
        this.Font = this.font;
    }
}
```

The problem, as noted in the comment, is that I need to know when the button's superview is unloaded so that I can dispose of the subscription. I can easily get access to the superview, but I can't find any hooks to be notified when that superview is unloaded.

Does anyone know of any way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `MovedToSuperView` use `WillMoveToSuperView` - it will get called twice, once when the Button is added to a View (i.e. => Subscribe), and once when the Button is about to be trashed (where `newSuperview` will be null).

Also, you can write this a bit more elegantly using `SerialDisposable`:

```
private sealed class DynamicTypeAwareButton : UIButton
{
    private readonly IObservable<Unit> dynamicTypeChanged;
    private readonly UIFont font;
    private SerialDisposable subscription = new SerialDisposable();

    public override void WillMoveToSuperView(UIView newView)
    {
        base.WillMoveToSuperView();

        // Whenever SerialDisposable.Disposable is assigned, it throws
        // away the previous one. That means, even if the Button gets
        // moved to a new non-null View, we're still not leaking a 
        // subscription
        if (newView != null) 
        {
            this.subscription.Disposable = this.dynamicTypeChanged
                .StartWith(Unit.Default)
                .Subscribe(_ => this.UpdateFont());
        } 
        else 
        {
            this.subscription.Disposable = Disposable.Empty;
        }
    }

    public void UpdateFont()
    {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```